# Virtual host for a Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat6, virtualhost

I have a Apache 2.2 that is connected with a Tomcat 6. The Apache has a vHost that rooted from an address http://test.server.com to the Tomcat. This works fine. But so I´m landed in the webapp folder and if I would like to serve to a application called "foobar", I must type http://:test.server.com/foobar 
I would like an URL, maybe foobar.server.com that rooted directly in the correct webapp folder "foobar". The user should not see that he is in a subfolder of the Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName www.sub.domain.tld
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. You describe the settings of the Apache. This is also right, but on the Tomcat-side, it does not help, unfortunately.